# I want to extract a text string on the webpage which is written in the form of table, but I am getting null in return

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
     WebElement e5 = d1.findElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]");
                         String a = e5.getText();
                         System.out.println(a);

_____________________________________________________________________________
```

I have used getText method. The data is stored in the table, so the strategy which I am making use of is that first of all i want to get to the location of that data using xPath funda and then I need to extract the data corresponding to that location. Can anyone suggest a better way to do so.Thanks in advance.

pls find below the html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form method="post" action="">
<input id="_csrf" type="hidden" value="psJdnI5AnxjGqT2knrZG" name="_csrf">
<div class="innercontainer">
<div class="leftpanel">
<h2>MY ACCOUNT</h2>
<div>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<strong>Membership ID:</strong>
</td>
<td>2800000101</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="rightpanel">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

---

html page added above. Kindly suggest some alternative

Comment: For a better way we need the HTML. Also check it is not under a frame / iframe / modal or under a child window

Comment: ok just copying the entire html

Comment: so assuming u want `2800000101` u can have xpath as `//td[contains(.,'Membership ID:')]/following-sibling::td[0]`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(.,'Membership ID:')]/following-sibling::td[0]"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.11 seconds
F

Comment: my mistake ... its `td[1]` instead of `td[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clean up your Xpath, however this should help

```
   WebElement tableText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourXpath"));
   String actualText = tableText.getAttribute("textContent");

   System.out.println(actualText)
```

Comment: Hi Zach ...what is textContent parameter in the statement above getAttribute("textContent");?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM attributes of An Element via DOM Panel there is an an attribute called TextContent which is the innerText of the element

Steps 
Right click on an element using Firebug and Click Inspect with Firebug
Hover to the Highlighted Element and Right Click
Click Inspect DOM Panel

Comment: Actually, I want handle an ajax response...how to do that?